# Is using protected_multilib with yum a bad thing?

Tags: linux, yum, rpm

I have a case where I would like to install multiple versions of a package installed side-by-side. The rpms have been crafted such that the paths of the files are different - so there should be no conflict there.

I have tested that this can be installed correctly (side-by-side) using yum as long as `protected_multilib=false` - I also force `installonlypkgs` to the same name and `installonly_limit=0`.

My question is, is this a bad thing to do (and reading around - this seems to be discouraged, but can't find an obvious reason why - or how one should do it differently.) I am not interested in any of the files being available via standard system paths (for example symlink in `/usr/bin/` for current version etc.) I just want the files to be present to allow my build system to work correctly against versioned packages.